# fs.promises.writeFile is rerendering page Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

```
ipcMain.on("saveData", async (event, data) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop the default behavior of the event

  let sData = JSON.stringify(data);
  try {
    //await fs.promises.writeFile("src/store/storageFile.json", sData);
  } catch (err) {}
});
```

Why fs.promises.writeFile is rerendering page ? How can I prevent rerender?

Comment: How do you know that FS is responsible for the re-rendering ? Are you sure it's not React.strictmode re-rendering through an effect for exemple ? Please, add the rest of the relevant logic for context.

Comment: I found the problem, in my main js there are function that renders my app in every changing in my file, so when ı write anything to the file app recognizes it and rerender page.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the solution. Based on that thought, i would still recommend that next time you post all the "relevant" code (don't just post the whole project, only  the files that are actually helpfull or related) as you can probably see there was no way for anyone to help you with what you provided.